# Generate 1MB image python

Tags: python, django

I need to generate 1MB image file to do a teste on django. I can only set the image size, but not the image file size.

```
image_file = StringIO()
image = Image.new('RGBA', size=(4000,4000), color=(256,0,0))
image.save(image_file, 'png')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to save a BMP image, which has no compression:

```
In [1]: Image.new('L', (1024, 1024)).save('/tmp/x.bmp')
In [2]: !ls -alh /tmp/x.bmp
-rw-r--r--  1 wolever  wheel   1.0M Jul 13 16:46 /tmp/x.bmp
```

And if you need to use PNG, you can fill it with random data:

```
In [3]: import os
In [4]: Image.frombytes('L', (1024, 1024), os.urandom(1024*1024)).save('/tmp/x.png')
In [5]: !ls -alh /tmp/x.png
-rw-r--r--  1 wolever  wheel   1.0M Jul 13 16:49 /tmp/x.png
```

Answer (score -1):

File size depends on **what is** on the picture. PNG compresses the data, so the blank image would be way smaller than a photo (with the same resolution).

You may use an iterative approach: filp one pixel, save to file, check size. Then flip another one. Faster: use bisection.

Comment: Downvote because flipping one pixel at a time then checking the file size is computationally infeasible (it's ~O(N^2) where N is about 1024*1024), and bisection doesn't make sense in this context (ie, because the least compressed image will be totally random, where bisection is generally deterministic).